# Using a node module in ng-boilerplate (angular)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, node-modules

I am writing a web app using ng-boilerplate (https://github.com/ngbp).  I want to use a few node modules (for example: npm install node-rsa) but after installing the node module, I can't figure out how to access the node module in my angular controller.  It would be cool if I could access it through dependency injection.  Is that possible?